# Finding sum of n odd numbers following a given integer

Tags: python-3.x

Read an integer N that is the number of test cases that follows. Each test case contains two integers X and Y. Print one output line for each test case that is the sum of Y odd numbers from X including it if is the case. For example: for the input 4 5, the output must be 45, that is: 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13 for the input 7 4, the output must be 40, that is: 7 + 9 + 11 + 13

Comment: Please post what you did so far.

Comment: Please post what you have come up with so far and where you are stuck so that we can understand what you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I was just working on it.

```
x = int(input("Enter Value of X: "))
y = int(input("Enter Value of Y: "))
result = 0
itt = 0
while itt != y:
   if x % 2 == 0:
      x += 1
   else:
     itt += 1
     result += x
     x += 1

print(result)
```

Comment: why do you put a `continue` inside the `ìf`?

Comment: You are right. @SembeiNorimaki. Just update my answer